# Manipulate with discrete values

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I know how to use Manipulate and set ranges of values, but I would like to have two labeled boxes that you can chose from to change a value of parameter.

```
Manipulate[Plot[a + b*x, {x, 1, 100}], {a, -1, 10}, {b, -10, 10}]
```

So for example I would like $a$ to have two values that you can choose from and are labeled. Would you give any hints?

Comment: documentation: Manipulate / Scope / Controls

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading about it in Documentation -> I didn't know where to look. What do you think, should I delete this question?

Comment: If you find the exact answer somewhere in documentation then I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a Setter to get discrete values of the manipulating parameter, such as:

```
  Manipulate[Plot[a + b*x, {x, 1, 10}], {a, {-1, 10}}, {b, -10, 10, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

You may choose instead a radio button, or a check box. For example, for the CheckBox it works as follows:

```
 Manipulate[Plot[a + b*x, {x, 1, 10}], {a, {-10, 10}}, {b, -10, 10}, 
 ControlType -> {Checkbox, Slider}]
```

[image]

As you have seen, for the slider one can use the option `Appaarance->"Labeled"`. I, however, like a custom-made annotation. I will show it within the example of a `RadioButtonBar`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[a + b*x, {x, 1, 10}], 
{{a, -10,Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style["a= ", Blue, 14], Style[a, Red, 14]}], 
     ImageSize -> {80, 40}]}, {-10, 0, 10}}, 
{{b, 5, Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style["b= ", Blue, 14], Style[b, Red, 14]}], 
     ImageSize -> {80, 40}]}, 0, 10}, 
 ControlType -> {RadioButtonBar, Slider}]
```

[image]

I intentionally highlighted here different styling features of the annotation, which are not necessary to use, if not needed. I also recommend to play with the parameters of the `ImageSize` to fix the size of the panel in which the annotation is displayed. This size depends on the length of the texts and figures you are showing and cannot be fixed in advance.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Manipulate[
 Plot[a + b*x, {x, 1, 100}], {a, -1, 10, 1}, {b, -10, 10, 1}]

Comment: I'm not sure that this addresses the question adequately.

Comment: It was only a hint. For instance, if lough_or_cry want two values  for a say -1 and 10 he can do Manipulate[ Plot[a + b*x, {x, 1, 100}], {a, -1, 10, 11}, {b, -10, 10, 1}]